# weighted mysql results from matching 2 columns accross 3 tables (3rd being joining table)

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search

Ok, I'll do my best to explain this clearly. I am at a loss as to what to do next. I'm building a D.A.M (digital asset manager). I have a table of Assets, a table for tags, and asset table to join the 2. Here is my search query:

```
            SELECT a.*
    FROM assets a, tags t, asset_tags at
    WHERE 1*MATCH (a.notes) AGAINST ('{$searchQuery}' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    UNION
    SELECT a.*
    FROM assets a, tags t, asset_tags at
    WHERE 2*MATCH (t.name) AGAINST ('{$searchQuery}' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    AND at.tag_id = t.id
    AND a.id = at.asset_id
    GROUP BY a.id
```

given assets:

asset1: tags= ford, description = "unlike the fusion.."
asset2: tags= hyundai, description = "this color is a fusion.."
asset3: tags= ford, description = ""
asset4: tags= ford,fusion; description = "This ford fusion has ..."

the search "ford Fusion", based on the weight applied in the above query the order should be: 4,1,3,2

instead i'm getting 1,2,4,3. I'm guessing this is because I am grouping by a.id so its not adding how many times a tag is indexed on a particular asset. also it's not weighing the 2 queries together.

I'm looking at having a thousand or less tags but up to and over a million assets. I Want to keep things as efficient as possible.

Where do i go next? Is there a piece of this puzzle I am missing?